# Understanding how twilio manages multiple numbers from same twilio account

Tags: twilio

My question is when we buy multiple numbers from same twilio account, what is the parameter that makes the numbers different? Is it the client name or is there something else? Suppose that I want my tablet and phone to be linked to same twilio number then they will have different client name, Is that right? Please can some one explain.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

> Suppose that I want my tablet and phone to be linked to same twilio number then they will have different client name

To do this you could set the Voice request URL of your Twilio phone number to a URL that returns TwiML containing multiple `<Client>` nouns.  you can set it up to eather dial sequentially:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>bob</Client>
    </Dial>
    <Dial>
        <Client>alice</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

In this scenario Twilio will dial Bob first.  If Bob does not answer, Twilio will dial alice.

You can also simul-dial multiple clients:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>bob</Client>
        <Client>alice</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

In this scenario Twilio will dial Bob and Alice at the same time and Twilio will bridge the inbound PSTN call to which ever answers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: suppose that from single account I bought many numbers, then they all will have same auth token and account sid, right ? they will differ in only one thing that is client name, right ?

Comment: correct.  Your authtoken and account sid are scopped to the whole account.